# How to execute some function after login or logout in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to get a historial of users when login and logout from application.
I use `devise` for `model user` in Frontend (I have a `model adminUser` for `ActiveAdmin`/`Devise` login in Backend)

How can I execute function where I save that information in other table?

Current routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In devise I override the default controllers while using super to invoke a method of the same name in the parent, after that's run you can then execute whatever you want.

For example:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

   # POST /resource/sign_in
   def create
      super
      # >> Do some stuff
   end

   # DELETE /resource/sign_out
   def destroy
      super
      # >> Do some different stuff
   end

end
```

I'm not 100% sure that's what you mean, but I hope it's helpful

Comment: Ok it's works, but in `destroy` method, How I get the `current_user` if this is `nil`? The object resource is `nil`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you could run something before super, while the current_user still exists?

Comment: In order this to work you will have to pass `module` to `device_for` in your config/routs.rb `devise_for :users, module: 'users'`